# BeautifulSoup prettify encoding non-English (Cyrillic) characters strangely

Tags: python-3.x, beautifulsoup, cyrillic, prettify

I have HTML with Cyrillic characters. I am using BeautifulSoup4 to process this. It works great, but when I go to prettify, it converts all the Cyrillic characters to something else. Here is a dummy example using Python3:

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

hello = '<span>Привет, мир</span>'
soup = BeautifulSoup(hello, 'html.parser')
print("Before prettify:\n{}".format(soup))
soup = soup.prettify(formatter='html')
print("\nafter prettify:\n{}".format(soup))
```

Here is the output it generates:

```
Before prettify:
<span>Привет, мир</span>

after prettify:
<span>
 &Pcy;&rcy;&icy;&vcy;&iecy;&tcy;, &mcy;&icy;&rcy;
</span>
```

It's formatting the HTML properly (putting the tags on their lines), but it's converting the Cyrillic characters to something else (I'm not even certain what encoding that is, to be honest.)

I have tried various things to prevent this; `prettify(encoding=None, formatter='html')`, `prettify(encoding='utf-8', formatter='html')`, I have also tried changing the way I create the soup object: `soup = BeautifulSoup(hello.encode('utf-8'), 'html.parser')` and `soup = BeautifulSoup(hello, 'html.parser', from_encoding='utf-8')` - nothing seems to change what happens to the Cyrillic characters during prettify.

I figure this must be a very simple mistake I am making with encoding parameters somewhere, but after searching the internet and BS4 documentation, I am unable to figure this out. **Is there a way to use BeautifulSoup's prettify, but maintain the Cyrillic characters as they were originally, or is this not possible?**

EDIT: I have realized now (thanks to DYZ's answer), that removing `formatter='html'` from the call to prettify will stop BeautifulSoup from converting the Cyrillic chars. Unfortunately, this also removes any `&nbsp` chars in the document. After having a look at [BS4's output-formatters documentation](https://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/#output-formatters), it seems the solution is to create a custom formatter using BS's Formatter class, and specifying this in the call to prettify - `soup.prettify(formatter=my_formatter)`. I'm not sure yet what that would entail, though. I have posted [this Stackoverflow question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69790205/prettify-with-beautifulsoup-using-a-formatter-that-will-preserve-nbsp-and-cyri) to try and solve this separate problem. (format prettify to both preserve &nbsp and Cryillic characters EDIT: See answer to that question - I finally figured it out.)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From the [documentation](https://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/#output-formatters):

> If you pass in formatter="html", Beautiful Soup will convert Unicode characters to HTML entities whenever possible.

If this is not desirable, do not use the HTML formatter:

```
soup.prettify()
#'<span>\n Привет, мир\n</span>'
```

Comment: Ah yes, I recall now why I was doing this (adding formatter="html" in the call to prettify). If I don't add this, prettify removes my  &nbsp characters and converts them to whitespace, which messes up the way the HTML displays, unfortunately.

Comment: In case anyone is curious, I have solved the problem mentioned above - you can supply a custom formatter to prettify which will preserve both the Cyrillic and the &nbsp. See the answer I posted to my other stackoverflow question here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69790205/prettify-with-beautifulsoup-using-a-formatter-that-will-preserve-nbsp-and-cyril/69790637#69790637